# Error in android studio when building ionic 4 app

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, ionic4

I run Ionic 4 in Android Studio and am getting the error:

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be
>   smaller than version 19 declared in library
>   [**tested_artifact**::CordovaLib]
>   E:\MYAPP\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 1     Suggestion: use
>   a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,      or increase this
>   project's minSdk version to at least 19,      or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `application build.gradle` file.

[image]

Then change the min version to 19:

[image]